# Grails 3 does not create empty tables

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails3

I have just upgraded my app from Grails 2 to Grails 3 and I have an issue that grails 3 does not create a table, which should have no data inside it.

I am then getting an error, when I create a Criteria on this domain class.

When I run grails 2 app, it creates the table in database, but grails 3 does not create it.

I cannot even save anything to the table.

The table looks like this.

```
class PublishService {

    int numberOfDays
    int numberOfPublishedJobOffers
    int prize

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I think it cannot have Service in the name of the domain class.

Comment: Which version of Grails 3 are you using?

Comment: Grails 3.1.9 it is. I solved it by renaming the table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the the name of the table to mapping e.g.

```
static mapping = {
    table 'publishservice'
}
```

Comment: It does not work. It seems one simply cannot call a domain class somethingService.

Comment: I think Mike is suggesting renaming the class, but add the mapping so the underlying DB table doesn't have to change.   Seems like that would work, if it's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in Grails 3.1.11 and 3.2.3. Upgrading to either of those versions should resolve your issue.